# Screen displays only in top left corner of window

Tags: python, pygame

I'm starting to explore Python and Pygame, however I am running into a problem. Everything I draw to the screen is only displayed in the top left quarter of the window. I thought it was my code but any demo programs I tried also display the same way.

Demo code from thenewboston on youtube

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load("Background.jpg").convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mouse_c, (x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

In the video his displays correctly and mine looks like this
[image: screenshot of game rendering only in the top left quarter of the screen]

Using:

- Python 2.7.4 32 bit
- pygame 1.9.1 32 bit
- mac 10.8.3 64 bit on macbook pro retina

I think either it has to do with the retina display or I installed something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: code works great on my machine. Try to install python and pygame from scratch and see what happens (using virtualenv).
And no, retina has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I am still running into the same problem after using the virtualenv python

Comment: try this: `screen.blit(mouse_c, (50,50))`   if this will work, then the pygame mouse module is not working properly.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you are getting at here. I did as you said and the mouse just stopped working as I thought it would. all this does is set the coordinates of the image. Not sure how to explain the original mouse movements but I'll try. the ball would move within the background image relative to where the mouse was in the whole window (ball in center of gradient while mouse was in the center of the window)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, in fact, with the resolution of the retina screen.  In order to get pygame to work correctly, download setresx and use it to set your resolution to any setting without HiDPI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been working on my old computer for a month because I couldn't figure this out. I am at work but I will definitely give this a shot when I get home.