# Can you get Pygame to work properly on retina screens?

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

I have the same problem as here: [Screen displays only in top left corner of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368487/pygame-display-only-in-top-left-corner-of-window)

The pygame container is messed up by the high resolution retina screen. I have searched around and haven't found any one with an answer other than "change your resolution".

Is it possible to fix this in the game, so that the player doesn't have to fix it themselves? Either fixing the bug in pygame or resizing the resolution when the game starts? Maybe it could work only in fullscreen somehow?

**TO CLARIFY:** I don't want to have to change the screen resolution manually, but within the pygame-code.

Comment: *"fixing the bug in pygame"* is a bit out-of-scope for SO...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame display only in top left corner of window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368487/pygame-display-only-in-top-left-corner-of-window), unless there's a particular reason the solution there didn't work for you.

Comment: If what you're actually looking for is different answers to the previous question, then **adding a bounty** would have been better than opening a new question.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan It's not a duplicate, because the solution there is to change the resolution for the entire screen

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is it? How do I add the reason of why I want another answer?

Comment: Just add a comment to the question clarifying what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you've figured this out at all yet as it's been a while. But you can enable low resolution mode for the pygame window in the Macs application settings. Then you don't have to change your resolution every time. I still haven't figured out how to fix this in code though.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471

Edit: I'm assuming it's a Mac you're using.

Answer (score -3):

I am afraid there isn't any way. `pygame` hasn't been updated for a while and I think development has stopped. I ran into the same problem and ended up dealing with using a program called `setresx` when necessary. The problem can also be fixed by hooking up your computer to an external monitor. I know you can get some portable ones that you can put on the side of your screen.

As to changing the code, as far as I'm concerned it isn't `pygame` that there is anything wrong with, but technically the screen. That said, you might be able to change the library itself to handle the issue.